# how to change the color configuration of QtCreator/QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

The selected widget on left UI will have a grey background color at the right widgets list (just like the highlight of current line).

The colors are too similar that I can hard to distinguish them.

How can I change it to other color such as red, blue and green?

An example image here:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Designer is a standard Qt application. As such, it supports some [command line options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication), including `-stylesheet`:

> -stylesheet= *stylesheet*, sets the application [styleSheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html). The value must be a path to a file that contains the Style Sheet.

This allows to set a custom QSS for the application, similarly to what `QApplication.setStyleSheet()` does, with the difference that the command line option only accepts a file, while `setStyleSheet()` only accepts a string (the contents of the style sheet).

Now, a simple solution would be to create a file that sets the `selection-background-color` (and appropriate contrasting color for the text with `selection-color`) for tree views, based on the [QSS documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html); for instance:

```
QTreeView {
    selection-background-color: green;
    selection-color: white;
}
```

Then run Designer as follows:

```
> designer -stylesheet customstyle.qss
```

This won't be right, though. Qt Style Sheets (QSS) are always propagated to children, meaning that **any** tree view will use those selection colors, including widgets that are being *designed*. You obviously don't want that.

Luckily, Qt developers set object names for most hardcoded widgets, including Designer children.

The object inspector is a custom Designer plugin form used as a QDockWidget, with a `qt_designer_objectinspector_dock` object name set (see <sup>[1] note</sup>); this means that you can use a proper [selector type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for that:

```
QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView {
    selection-background-color: green;
    selection-color: white;
}
```

The above means: apply the given properties (background and text colors for selected items) to any QTreeView that is a direct child of a QDockWidget having an object name equal to `qt_designer_objectinspector_dock`.

Note that for certain styles, the above properties may not be enough.
In this case, you can add a related rule by using specific [sub-controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls); doing this will theoretically ensure that the selected items will always have those colors, no matter the underlying style:

```
QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView {
    selection-background-color: green;
    selection-color: white;
}

QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView::item:selected {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Note that Qt Creator uses a slightly different object naming approach. In that case, the selector would be `QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget`. So, if you want, you can use a "centralized" qss file that will eventually work for both of them, using a comma to separate selectors having common rules:

```
QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView,
QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget QTreeView {
    selection-background-color: green;
    selection-color: white;
}

QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView::item:selected,
QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget QTreeView::item:selected {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Just remember that QSS rules are context based: in the rare case you are designing a QMainWindow with a QDockWidget named as above with a QTreeView inside it, the colors will be applied. You may consider adding further restrictions to the rule, for instance:

```
QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock #qt_designer_objectinspector QTreeView,
QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget #ObjectInspector QTreeView {
    ...
}
```

In reality, just using proper names will be a simpler solution.

<sup>[1]: Designer tool windows are actual widgets, they get reparented and set as widgets of QDockWidgets. The private `addToolWindows()` (in `qttools/src/designer/src/designer/mainwindow.cpp`) sets the dock's object name by appending `_tool` to the original designer tool widget object name.</sup>

Comment: I don't know what happened. I set it to green or red and the color has been darker grey. Anyway, it's useful and easy for distinguishing.
By the way, I use it by `qtcreator.exe -stylesheet stylesheet.qss`

Comment: @popter Did you use the exact syntax above (for my last snippet) in the QSS file? How did you run the `designer` command above? If you did it in a terminal or command prompt, you should probably get some output from it: can you provide it? Note that command line arguments work differently on windows. Try `designer -stylesheet=customstyle.qss` or eventually `designer /stylesheet=customstyle.qss`.

Comment: I run it in cmd.exe by `qtcreator.exe -stylesheet stylesheet.qss`. It output nothing to terminal, which makes the color dark grey. `-stylesheet=style.qss` has the same effect. 
I also tried the `designer.exe` in PyQt5, which seems to be not useful  because it is originally dark grey.

@musicamante

Comment: @popter Can you try to also add `-style=fusion` to the command line? Qt stylesheets should always override the base QStyle, but there are some exceptions for platform styles I don't quite remember right now. Also: 1. I don't know if the `stylesheet` argument is CWD aware, try to provide the *absolute* path to that file (possibly using quotes if the path has spaces, and eventually replacing Windows' backslash with standard forward slash: `C:\whatever\style.qss` > `C:/whatever/style.qss`); 2. use the first QSS of my question, the one without dedicated selector types (`QTreeView { ... }`).

Comment: I have tried all what you said. I also tried wildcard, the color style will be useful to other `QTreeView` except those in the Object Inspector. It seems that the Object Inspector allows only grey. I'm sure the selector `QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock QTreeView` is correct because the attributes `background-color` and `color`  work well.  It doesn't matter. Dark grey is enough for distinguishing. I will try more and let you know when there's progress. 
@musicamante

Comment: @popter Interesting. AFAIK, setting a stylesheet on an item view should always override the behavior of the underlying style, but QSS are known to be somehow inconsistent depending on many factors in certain cases, with the only (but not always completely safe) exception of using the "fusion" style, which is the only style that is normally considered as reference for *full* QSS property settings. I've briefly seen your comment about using the `::item:selected` selector (which was going to be my next suggestion); was it meant to show the attempt of your above comment, or does it actually work?

Comment: Yes, I just tried. `::item:selected`  can achieve it. @musicamante

Comment: `selection-background-color` and  `selection-color` can only change the color from grey to darker grey. @musicamante

Comment: @popter Please don't rush comments (nor answers!). We're here to find a proper solution (that will help not only you, but any future reader). Take your time, do proper tests and *then* reply. If `selection-*-color` doesn't work, there's probably a reason for it, and we may be able to answer that thoroughly. Creating a separate answer that uses the same similar concepts without explaining the underlying aspects of those differences may be extremely confusing. Let's collaborate and find the problem, and either provide an unique, comprehensive answer, or two related but *distinguishable* ones.

Comment: The selector for Object Inspector for QtCreator is `QDockWidget #ObjectInspector`(mention the space)while the QDesigner is `QDockWidget#qt_designer_objectinspector_dock`. I get it by `grep` the source code.

Comment: @popter Can you check if it also works with `QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget` for QtCreator?

Comment: I tried. `QDockWidget#ObjectInspectorDockWidget` works well for QtCreator. @musicamante

Comment: @popter Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly. Please let me know if there's some remaining issue about it.